# Series in pandas

Tags: python-2.7

```
import pandas as pd;
s=pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,5]);
total=0;
for i in s:
    print(s[i]);
```

For the above code the output is:
2
3
4
5
5
5

Why the output is not 
1
2
3
4
5
5
What does s[i] represent.

Comment: please accept an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

`for i in s` already iterates over the items in `s`. Just do `print(i)`.

`s[i]` returns the value in the `i`-th position (or index) in `s`. (`s` is zero-indexed).
So your code only prints `s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5], s[5]`.

Answer (score 0):

`for i in s` returns the elements of `s = [1,2,3,4,5,5]`

if you want a classical for loop you have to do it like this `for i in range(len(s))`

Which is not that nice :)

These are your options

```
for i in s:
    print(s);

for i in range(len(s)):
    print(s[i]);
```